# Partial refresh after OK in name picker control

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

how can I establish a partial refresh after I select the OK button in the xe:namePicker control ?

I only have the for property which does copy the selected value in the assigned field.

The onchange event for that field does not always seem to recognize the value change.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce onChange not working to identify the scenarios. I'm not aware of an issue with it.

Comment: reprodude? yes it happens all the time (read: not working). if I add a simple print("beats me") in the onChange event nothings happens when the Edit Box get value from name picker control.

Comment: is there a way to get a handle on the close event of the dialog?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of an Edit Box, I would recommend using Dojo Name Text Box, as covered [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_9.0.1/user/extlib_controlref_djextnametextbox.html). It avoids the need for validation - with an Edit Box even though you provide a Name Picker, users can still enter values manually and can edit them after selecting from the name Picker. The Dojo Name Text Box and Dojo List Text Box are the only controls I use with pickers and almost always use onChange with them, without issue.

One caveat is that the Events tab defaults to onClick. On more than one occasion I've coded onClick instead of onChange, but it's easily identifiable and rectifiable.

Comment: I have a feeling that the onChange event is triggered. the (new) value in the "for" field is not available in the event (yet). could that be?